# Subquery returned more than 1 value no clue where the issue is?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT  MAX(te.StoreID) AS StoreID, 
        SUM(te.Price * te.Quantity) AS Sales, 
        SUM(te.Cost * te.Quantity) AS Cost, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT t.TransactionNumber) AS Trxn, 
        SUM(te.Quantity) AS Quantity 
FROM    TransactionEntry te 
        INNER JOIN [Transaction] t 
            ON te.TransactionNumber = t.TransactionNumber 
                AND te.StoreID = t.StoreID 
        LEFT JOIN item i 
            ON te.itemID = i.ID 
        LEFT JOIN Department d 
            ON i.DepartmentID = d.ID 
WHERE   d.ID <> 8 AND DATEDIFF(day, t.Time, GETDATE()) = 1 
        AND t.WebInvoiceID <> (select WebInvoiceID from [Transaction] where WebInvoiceID>0) 
GROUP   BY te.StoreID
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line:

```
AND t.WebInvoiceID <> (select WebInvoiceID from [Transaction] where WebInvoiceID > 0 )
```

One way to fix this is to use `NOT IN` since the subquery returns multiple rows.

```
AND t.WebInvoiceID NOT IN (select WebInvoiceID from [Transaction] where WebInvoiceID>0)
```

Another way is by using `NOT EXISTS` which I preferred more

```
WHERE   d.ID <> 8 AND DATEDIFF(day, t.Time, GETDATE()) = 1 
        AND NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM [Transaction] tr
            WHERE t.WebInvoiceID = tr.WebInvoiceID
                AND tr.WebInvoiceID > 0
        )
```

If not mistaken, based from your original logic, you don't a subquery to filter out `WebInvoiceID` which are greater than zero. This can be simplified as:

```
WHERE   d.ID <> 8 AND DATEDIFF(day, t.Time, GETDATE()) = 1 
        AND t.WebInvoiceID > 0
```

Comment: AWESOME! IT WORKED!

Comment: @DannyRyu If it worked, then you should mark Jon Woo's answer as Accepted.